# Headless CraftCMS: How can I tell Craft to load live preview from a different (sub)domain?

Tags: live-preview, headless

I will be using CraftCMS (Craft Solo 3.3.18.4) in headless mode as the backend for a Rails app. The Craft instance lives on a different subdomain.

How do I instruct craft to use the rails app URI when loading live preview in the preview iframe?

For example, if we presume
`admin.domain.com` for craft admin and
`domain.com` for the front end

How do I make the live preview frame to load from the live app?
`domain.com/posts/first-posts-slug?x-craft-live-preview=2OcHezCnU8&token=lY6F...`

Answer (score 3):

Since [Craft 3.3.1](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#331---2019-09-06), you can create a custom [alias](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases) that resolves to your frontend base URL, and add that alias to the relevant [preview targets'](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sections-and-entries.html#preview-targets) "URL Format" setting.

For example, assuming you put something like the below in your `config/general.php` file:

```php
'aliases' => [
    '@previewBaseUrl' => 'https://domain.com',
],
```

...you'd be able to use that `@previewBaseUrl` alias in your preview targets, e.g. `@previewBaseUrl/posts/{slug}`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. I need to modify the default preview target which gets pulled in an iframe when I click the preview button. Will report if this works.